# Permission check for JSF outcome using apache shiro

Tags: security, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, shiro

I have a JSF2 based web-application secured with [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org). In my application I have some links like

```
<h:link outcome="someOutcome" value="my Link"/>
```

or action-links like

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.someAction}" value="my Action" />
```

The JSF outcome "someOutcome" might be configured in a JSF navigation-rule to redirect to `/some/url.xhtml`.

My shiro configuration (`shiro.ini`) contains an entry for the corresponding URL:

```
/some/url.xhtml = perms[someRight]
```

And my backing-bean `myBean` is annotated like this:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class MyBean {
    @RequiresPermissions('someRight')
    public String someAction()
    {
        // do something
        return null;
    }
}
```

My requirement now is to disabled the links, if the permissions of current user are not sufficient.

Of course, I could add something like `disabled="#{subject.isPermitted('someRight')}"` to the `<h:link>`/`<h:commandLink>` components, but this way I would duplicate configuration which is already available via `shiro.ini` respectively annotations.

I'm thinking of something like

```
<h:link outcome="someOutcome"
        disabled="#{security.isOutcomeAllowed('someOutcome')}"
        value="my Link" />
```

which I could wrap in a composite-component to only specify `someOutcome` once. But how could the `security`-bean look like? Or is this the wrong approach?

Does anybody know a smart way for obtaining my goals?

Comment: Maybe the JSF library for Shiro can help you with your goal: http://deluan.github.io/shiro-faces/